# Как запустить службу брандмауэр в windows 10, если она остановлена

Tags: windows, windows-10

Как запустить службу брандмауэр в windows 10, если она остановлена?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эммм, в строке "Испоняемый файл" есть команда - попробуй ее от имени админа запустить

Comment: где и как запустить?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что ты оставил порносборку и продолжаешь наступать на грабли, которых в ванильной системе нет?

Comment: эмм, вроде на stackoverflow спрашиваешь, а как консоль открыть не знаешь? Win+R -> cmd -> команда